# Обрезать строку в гриде - не помещается

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Я пытаюсь заполнить мой DGV из БД, но одна из колонок содержит слишком длинную строку и поэтому ячейки остаются пустыми. Я бы хотела просто обрезать строку, но методы, которые ниже в коде, не работают. Как быть? На скрине сама проблема.

```
string nameConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string search = "SELECT * myTableName";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(nameConn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(search, con))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                {
                    using (DataTable data = new DataTable())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sda.Fill(data);
                        }

                        catch (Exception exc)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                        }
                            dataGridView5.DataSource = data;
                            //CType(dataGridView5.Columns(4), DataGridViewTextBoxColumn).MaxInputLength = 5;
                            //dataGridView5.Columns[4].MaxInputLength = 5;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx), не?

Comment: @AK да, получилось :) спасибо

Comment: Напишите тогда ответ - вдруг кому-то пригодится ещё.

Comment: Я не понял. Длинная строка же обрезается самим гридом, в конце появляется ellipsis (многоточие). Не? Или в начале строки идут пробелы и их нужно обрезать? Тогда, самым правильным будет обрезать эти пробелы ещё до вставки в БД (метод `Trim`).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov насколько я поняла, то это просто очень длинный стринг, поэтому DGV оставляет просто пустую ячейку. Потому что когда я записываю все это в документ типа json, у меня выходит около 3000 строк

Comment: Хм, действительно, есть такое дело. Потестил: строка длиной 10 тысяч символов отображается (с многоточием); 100 тысяч - совсем не показывается. Да, `DataGridView` известен тем, что глотает исключения. Что ж, тогда `Substring` действительно рулит.